# Best practice in accessing a single element of an array

Tags: javascript, filter

What is the best way to filter a single element from a javascript object

```
data.filter(({id}) => {return id === id})
```

I get a single element array and have to index it to access the elements. What is a get method to better handle this situation?

Comment: The code as posted will not filter anything out except `NaN` values; for everything else, `id === id` is always `true`.

Comment: `find()` would be better than `filter()` if you are trying to get one element out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

From MDN:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Example:

```js
const people = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Foo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bar',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Baz'
  }
];

const id = 2;

const result = people.find(person => person.id === id);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I need to use this for something else. Is this ECMA6? Will it work in older versions of IE? Thanks.

Comment: @lharby Yes, it's ES2015. No, it won't work in IE without transpiling with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io), but it will work in Edge.

Answer (score 1):

You should use different name for `id` property of the object

```
data.filter(({id:id2}) => {return id === id2})
```

You can also remove `{}` and `return` to make code shorter

```
data.filter(({id:id2}) => id === id2)
```

I won't destruct the object in this case

```
data.filter(o => o.id === id)
```